# "Could not find foo in PATH" - but it's right there

Tags: path, alias, command-not-found

I see the following behavior:

```
$ foo
Could not find foo in PATH
$ which foo
/usr/local/corp/bin/foo
$ readlink -f `which foo`
/path/to/opt/foo/foo
$ /usr/local/corp/bin/foo
starting foo, output for foo, blah blah blah
```

this is a Centos 7 machine with Linux kernel 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 . The shell is bash.

Notes:

- Yes, `/usr/local/corp/bin` is in my `$PATH`.
- `/usr/local/corp/bin/foo` is a symlink to `/path/to/actual/binary/foo`.
- `hash -r` doesn't help.

Comment: Does `hash -r` help?

Comment: Is that directory actually in your `PATH`?

Comment: @NasirRiley: See edit.

Comment: @user10489: See edit.

Comment: What does `echo "$PATH"` show? Please add it to your question. Also `type foo` please

Comment: See also [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: @roaima: I can't show you that. I mean, I'd have to rewrite a bunch of the paths there to avoid disclosing information.

Comment: @einpoklum just run `echo "$PATH" | sed 's|/sensitive/path|/some/path|g'`. We probably don't need to know the specific path names, just see what's there. We will need to see the output of `type -a foo` though. My first guess is that you've aliased it to something else. Does `\foo` work as expected?